# How to use a same instance of hiltViewModel among nested composable?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I have a composable function named 'Page' as a basic composable to hold NavHost for my app, please see architecture below:

```
@Composable
fun Page(viewModel: LdvToolViewModel = hiltViewModel(), scaffoldState: ScaffoldState, navController: NavHostController){
    val statusBarMode = viewModel.statusBarUiState
    val uiController = rememberSystemUiController()

    LaunchedEffect(statusBarMode){
        uiController.run {
            if(statusBarMode.isDarkContent){
                setStatusBarColor(color = Color.White, darkIcons = true)
            }else{
                setStatusBarColor(color = LdvOrange, darkIcons = false)
            }
        }
    }
    
    val navBuilder: NavGraphBuilder.() -> Unit = {
        composable(LdvPages.SEARCHING.name) { SearchUi(viewModel, scaffoldState = scaffoldState) }
        composable(LdvPages.ERROR.name) { ErrorUi(viewModel,scaffoldState = scaffoldState) }
        composable(LdvPages.PANEL.name) { PanelUi(scaffoldState,viewModel, mBaseViewModel) }
        composable(LdvPages.PrivacyPolicy.name){ PrivacyPolicy(scaffoldState)}
        composable(LdvPages.TermsOfUse.name){ TermsOfUse(scaffoldState)}
        composable(LdvPages.OpenSourceLicense.name){ OpenSourceLicense(scaffoldState)}
        composable(LdvPages.DebugPage.name){ DebugPage(viewModel)}
    }
    val start by derivedStateOf {
        if (...){
            LdvPages.PANEL.name }else if(...){
            LdvPages.ERROR.name
            }else{LdvPages.SEARCHING.name}
    }

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = start, builder = navBuilder)
    if(!isNfcEnable){
        viewModel.setNfcDisableContent()
        ErrorDialog(viewModel = viewModel){
            startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS));
        }
    }
    
}
```

As you can see that 'LdvToolViewModel' has been injected to 'Page' as hiltViewModel. To keep 'LdvToolViewModel' as one instance among lifecycles of nested-composable functions in navBuilder, I have to pass it as parameter to those functions. Is there any better way like I can somehow inject 'LdvToolViewModel' in those functions as hiltViewModel and meanwhile I can still have the injected hiltViewModel as a same instance?

Comment: Check hilt integration with compose navigation, where you can use `backStackEntry` as a parameter to retrieve `ViewModel` which scoped to navigation routes :  Link: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation

Answer (score 9):

Imagine you have a "HomeGraph", with "Home" as a parent destination, and few destination screens that should share the same ViewModel instance.

First get a NavBackStackEntry, by passing your parent route

```
val parentEntry: NavBackStackEntry = remember(navBackStackEntry) {
                navController.getBackStackEntry(Destination.HomeGraph.route)
            }
```

Then get an instance of a ViewModel by passing the parent NavBackStackEntry

```
val userViewModel = hiltViewModel<HomeViewModel>(parentEntry)
```

Also, remember that if you navigate to Destination.HomeGraph.route either from nested navigation or from a different graph a new instance of ViewModel will be created, so if you navigate within a single graph, navigate to startDestination e.g Destination.Home.route - this way you will keep the same ViewModel instance.

I don't thing we have a well-defined ViewModel sharing in compose as we had with a view system e.g by activityViewModels(), but keeping ViewModel state in graphs while user is not accessing them is a bad practice.
You can always pass the ViewModel in one of the graph extension function if necessary.

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.homeGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    navigation(
        startDestination = Destination.Home.route,
        route = Destination.HomeGraph.route
    ) {
        composable(Destination.Home.route) { navBackStackEntry ->
            val parentEntry = remember(navBackStackEntry) {
                navController.getBackStackEntry(Destination.HomeGraph.route)
            }
            val homeViewModel = hiltViewModel<HomeViewModel>(parentEntry)

            HomeRoute(
                viewModel = homeViewModel,
                onNavigate = { dest ->
                navController.navigate(dest.route)
            })
        }

        composable(Destination.Search.route) { navBackStackEntry ->
            val parentEntry = remember(navBackStackEntry) {
                navController.getBackStackEntry(Destination.HomeGraph.route)
            }
            val homeViewModel = hiltViewModel<HomeViewModel>(parentEntry)
            UserSupportRoute(
                viewModel = userViewModel,
                onNavigate = { dest ->
                navController.navigate(dest.route) {
                    popUpTo(Destination.Search.route) {
                        inclusive = true
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: and what if you have route with arguments? `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No destination with route HomeScreen is on the NavController's back stack. The current destination is route=HomeScreen/{ARG_PIN}`, this is headache

Comment: also what if I remove previous screen from backstack before opening the second one but want to use the same view model? it seems also say that there is nothing is on the backstack. so it seems it's not possible to just pass the data with parcelable argument to the other screen without using database or datastore, Navigation Component was allowing to easy pass parcelable data, shared view model is only for composable screens whiach are both at stack right now