# Android ViewModel - Nested UiState

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I need advice about how to design a code

I have a screen, let's call it J

- JScreen
- JUiState (error, isLoading, requestResponse)
- JViewModel

In the JViewModel, I will send a request and according to the response (requestResponse), I will display one of those 3 composable without routing (I mean `navigate`) just an if-else statement

- F1Content
- F2Content
- F3Content

All those 3 composable are forms with different fields

- F1Content (firstname, lastname, phone, email)
- F2Content (identifier, relative)
- F3Content (country, town, indicators, some contacts)

Concerning UiState and ViewModel,

- Should I create a UiState/ViewModel, for each of those 3 composables? If so, how should I pass their corresponding UiState/ViewModel during their creation? How to link them to the main ViewModel (JViewModel)?
- Or should I use `mutableStateOf` for the different fields in the different composable and everything their need must come from the JViewModel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As much I got your question I have one question will user have to go throw all content of f's like first f1,f2,f3 if yes then you can deal with this with two approaches :-

1. use nested navigation or
2. use all variables of form in JViewmdoel like any other screen and for second approach you will need same instanse of viewmodel so I will refer you this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73216665/how-to-use-a-same-instance-of-hiltviewmodel-among-nested-composable) of stackoverflow.

If user dont need to go all forms then you can simply use separate  viewModels for your flows. so it will go something like this :-

**JScreen -> anyform -> HomeScreen**

If you have any comments then let me know.

Comment: Thank you @heet kanabar.

The flow of the user is JScreen -> HomeScreen.

But the sequence in the JScreen will be: JScreen -> Sent request to API (/join/{token}) -> Analyze the Response -> If response contains F1, then present F1 composable? else if response contains F2, then present F2 composable? if response contains F3, then present F3 composable.

So I can say that F1, F2, and F3 are sub-screens of JScreen. JScreen exists as a wrapper acting as an entry point and is in charge of deciding which between F1, F2, and F3 should be displayed.

Comment: @MaelFosso then I would suggest you to use nested navigation and here I have a video for full explanation :- 1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FIEnIBq7Ups 2) https://youtu.be/h61Wqy3qcKg this might help you.